# Confidence/credibility intervals for a bernoulli trial

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, bernoulli-distribution, credible-interval

Say we have 
$$
X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p).
$$ I am interested in finding a 95% confidence and credibility interval.

For the credibility, I am assuming a uniform prior, giving me a posterior distribution 
$$
f(p | x) = \text{Beta}(x + 1, 2-x).
$$ 
Therefore we simply take the region of minimal measure such that the area under the distribution is 0.95

However, in the frequentist case for the confidence interval. I am mildly stumped as to how I would proceed. Could I have some insight on the intuition of this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, you’re looking for a confidence interval for $p$ based on a _single sample_? Or do you have multiple (possibly iid) draws from this distribution?

Comment: @Chaconne We have only 1 sample. So for example 1 coin flip with heads.

Comment: Then a frequentist has nothing to say to you. But why on earth will someone think you will have a frequentist confidence interval from a single sample?

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha . Indeed, the confidence might not be quite informative, but it does exist nonetheless. I am however interested in understand how one can find this.

Comment: Normally people will use normal approximations of the form $\hat p \pm z_\alpha*\sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1-\hat p)}{n}}$. In your case $n=1$, $\hat p=0$ or 1.

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha Thats what makes this problem tricky, xD. That won't work here.

Comment: Of course, it won't work. Your problem as it stands deterministic, it is equivalent to having 1000 Bernoulli samples with all equal to 1. My point is there is no randomness your problem.

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha just because people usually use a normal approximation does not mean that is all there is. It is really easy to construct a valid Frequentist interval for this problem; just take all values for which the LRT fails to reject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only have a single Bernoulli trial, there is little that can be done within the frequentist paradigm.  Your maximum-likelihood estimator (MLE) for $p$ is clearly $\hat{p} = X \sim \text{Bern}(p)$.  This is an unbiased estimator with unknown variance $\mathbb{V}(\hat{p}) = p(1-p)$.  Since you only have a single value in the sample, there is no basis to estimate the variance of the MLE$^\dagger$.  Nonetheless, a $(1-\alpha)$-level confidence interval for the parameter $p$ can be constructed as (hap-tip to [guy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/5339/guy) in  the comments):

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{CI}(1-\alpha) \equiv [\alpha X, 1 - \alpha (1-X)] & & & 0 < \alpha < 1.
\end{matrix}$$

This gives an interval estimator for the true probability parameter.  It is wider than the Bayesian credibility interval in the question, and thus represents a more robust estimate.

---

$^\dagger$ The maximum-likelihood estimator of the variance $\mathbb{V}(\hat{p})$ is zero, which is unhelpful.

Comment: Interesting, Under what conditions then can we obtain a confidence interval in the frequentist framework?

Comment: I disagree with this regarding it being impossible to do Frequentist inference. You can get a valid 95% interval by taking [0,.95] if X is zero and [0.05,1] if X is 1, which I assume is what you get by inverting the LRT. I would guess this interval is optimal in some sense (UMPU?).

Comment: @guy what is UMPU? Those intervals were also my guess for a confidence interval

Comment: @rannoudanames UMPU is uniformly most powerful unbiased, but I guess for a CI it should be something like minimal-length unbiased but I’m not sure of the terminology.

Comment: @guy: Can you show the pivotal quantity/working you are using for this confidence interval?  I don't see how you got this.

Comment: @Ben you don’t need a pivot to construct an interval estimate. You can check by direct computation that it has valid coverage, meaning that the infimum over p of the probability of coverage is at least 0.95.

Comment: Okay, yeah, got it.  I'll add an edit to the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @guy I am confused as to how you would see if the LRT fails to reject. The LR is : $\frac{p^x (1-p)^{1-x}}{x^x (1-x)^{1-x}}$. How do I move from here?

Comment: @rannoudanames $x$ is either 0 or 1, so the LR is $p$ when $X=1$ and $1-p$ when $X=0$. For the purposes of the LRT you should interpret $0^0 = 1$ so the denominator is $1$. The LRT then says to reject for $p<k$ when you get a 1 and reject for $p>1-k$ when you get a 0. Set $k=0.05$ to get the interval.

Comment: @guy Thank you! This makes sense! Having only one observation makes the approach slightly counterintuitive, but this makes much sense!